# The confusion on python encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii

I retrieved the data encoded in big5 from database,and I want to send the data as email of html content, the code is like this:

```
html += """<tr><td>"""        
html += unicode(rs[0], 'big5') # rs[0] is data encoded in big5
```

I run the script, but the error raised: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...... However, I tried the code in interactive python command line, there are no errors raised, could you give me the clue?

Comment: 'ascii' codec can't decode __what__ byte?

Comment: Did you mean `html += unicode(rs[0], 'big5')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `unicode()` is working correctly.  It is the concatenation, which is adding a unicode object to a byte string, that is causing trouble.  If you change the first line to `u'''<tr><td>'''`, (or `u'<tr><td>'`) it should work fine.

Edit: This means your error lies in the data that is already in `html` by the time python reaches this snippet:

```
>>> '\x9f<tr><td>' + unicode('\xc3\x60', 'big5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'\x9f<tr><td>' + unicode('\xc3\x60', 'big5')
u'\x9f<tr><td>\u56a5'
>>>
```

Comment: You should always deal with unicode objects when possible.  Decode input to unicode as soon as you can.  Encode output to a specific encoding (utf-8, for instance) as late as you can.  Use `codecs.open()` instead of the built-in `open()`, whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

If `html` is not already a unicode object but a normal string, it is converted to unicode when it is concatenated with the converted version of `rs[0]`. If `html` now contains special characters you can get a unicode error.

So the other contents of `html` also need to be correctly decoded to unicode. If the special characters come from string literals, you could use unicode literals (like `u"abcä"`) instead.

Comment: So what is the encoding of html shall I set with, so the html content displayed properly in mail?

Comment: @zhangzhong: You should use the encoding the HTML is encoded in. Only you can know what encoding that is, but if its the same as the other data its probably 'big5'.